# How to navigate from login screen to home screen that contains the bottom tabs

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Please help , im not sure how to make this work,
I dont know how to navigate from the login page to the home screen that will contain tabs, i only know how to navigate from the login to the home screen, but without the bottom tabs.

The error i get is: The component for route 'App'must be a React component.

```
const HomeStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    //Defination of Navigaton from home screen
    Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
    ViewBookings: {
      screen: ViewBookingsScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        //Header customization of the perticular Screen
        headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: '#0892d0',
        },
        headerTintColor: '#FFFFFF',
        title: 'View All Bookings',
        //Header title
      }, 
     },

  },
  {
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
      //Header customization of the perticular Screen
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#0892d0',
      },
      headerTintColor: '#FFFFFF',
      title: 'Welcome, User',
      //Header title
    },
  }
);
const AuthStack =  createStackNavigator({ SignIn: SignInScreen });
const App = createSwitchNavigator(
    {
      AuthLoading: AuthLoadingScreen,
      App: TabStack,
      Auth: AuthStack,
    },
    {
      initialRouteName: 'AuthLoading',
    }




);
const TabStack = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Home : { screen: HomeStack },

    Bookings: { screen: BookingStack},
    Reminders: { screen: ReminderStack},
  },

  {
    defaultNavigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      tabBarIcon: ({ focused, horizontal, tintColor }) => {
        const { routeName } = navigation.state;
        let IconComponent = Ionicons;
        let iconName;
        if (routeName === 'Home') {
          iconName = `ios-home`;
        } else if (routeName === 'Bookings') {
          iconName = `ios-book`;
        } else if (routeName === 'Reminders') {
          iconName = `ios-alarm`;
        }

        return <IconComponent name={iconName} size={25} color={tintColor} />;
      },
    }),
    tabBarOptions: {
      activeTintColor: '#0892d0',
      inactiveTintColor: 'gray',
    },
  }
);

export default createAppContainer(App);
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you authentication is successful you must call

this.props.navigation.navigate("Home");

This will navigate user to home screen.

You can decide route as per your requirement

Answer (score -1):

In Your Home Screen If you are importing your Login Component like

```
import {Whatever} from 'Wherever'
```

Change it to

```
import Whatever from 'Wherever'
```

Try by removing curly braces. Because as i see you have used **Default** with export. So when we used default we dont use braces while importing.

Comment: Terrible the question doesn't have those file included. How you do you know about his folder structure?